# Show series is convergent using taylor error

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

I'm honestly completely clueless on this problem, no idea where to start.

I've already done the majority of the problem, but it's the last part I can't figure out.

Here's what I was given:

$$f(x) = \sqrt{1+2x} \quad \text{for} -1/2 < x < \infty$$

From that I worked out it's taylorpolynomial of degree $1$, around the point $0$, and got:
$$T_1(x) = \sqrt{1} + x$$

I was then to find a constant $C > 0$ such that

$$|f(x) - T_1(x)| \leq C|x|^2, \quad \text{for} \; x\in [-1/4, 1/4]. $$

And found
$$C = \frac{\sqrt{6}}{18}$$

Now the last part of the problem is using the above to show that this series

$$\sum ^\infty _{n=2} (\sqrt{n^4 +2n^2}-1-n^2)$$

is convergent.

I have no idea how to proceed, I can't seem to find any connection between the two, so I must be missing something.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

$$\sqrt {n^4+2n^2}=n^2\sqrt {1+\frac {2}{n^2}} $$
$$=n^2 (1+\frac {2}{n^2})^\frac 12$$

$$=n^2 (1+\frac {1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{2n^4}(1+\epsilon (n)) $$

thus, your general term is
$$u_n=-\frac {1}{2n^2}(1+\epsilon (n)) $$
$$\sim \frac {-1}{2n^2} $$
thus the series is  absolutely convergent.

Comment: I'm still not seeing the connection between $C$ and your answer, could you elaborate?

Comment: @Fainted What is the criteria of convergence you want to use.

Comment: I used the limit comparison test.

Comment: Showing that the series is convergent is not something i have difficulty with, it was just mainly how I went from the previous results to showing that it converges, as the problem specifically states that I am to use the previous results.

Answer (score 2):

The expression in the sum can be written as $n^2$ times an $|f(x)-T_1(x)|$ where $x=\frac{1}{n^2}$. since $n$ is larger than or equal to $2$, the inequality is suitable as $|f(x)-T_1(x)|\leq\frac{C}{n^4}$. But, since multiplying by $n^2$ preserves inequalities (for $n>0$) we can say the entire expression is less than $\frac{C}{n^2}$. Therefore the sum is convergent as the infinite sum of $1/n^2$ from n = 2 to infinity is convergent. Is a proof of that necessary?